# newlib-cygwin build. no rule to make target install

Tags: gcc, centos, cygwin, newlib

I try to build newlib-cygwin on CentOS.  Got those error.

```
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/me/src/build-newlib/i686-pc-cygwin/newlib'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/me/src/build-newlib/i686-pc-cygwin/newlib'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/src/build-newlib/i686-pc-cygwin/newlib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/me/src/build-newlib/i686-pc-cygwin /winsup'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/src/build-newlib/i686-pc-cygwin/winsup'
make[1]: *** [install-target-winsup] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/src/build-newlib'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: are you doing a cross compilation ? How you configured ?